# PHP - Use array outside class?

Tags: php, arrays, class, function

I want to use an array outside it's class and I'm not quite sure on how to do this.

The class.

```
class Classname{
public function Functionname(){
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM...';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$sgArray[] = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   return $sgArray[] = $row['a'];
}
```

The code where I need the array(outside the class).

```
$var = 'somevalue';
$Array = ??? 
if(in_array($var, $Array)) {
    //enter code here
}
```

Hope someone can help me out since I'm still not too familiar with OOP.

Comment: what you wanna do? use the `$sgArray` you created in the function?

Comment: Don't `return` inside the `while` loop!  It would return on the first iteration, if you had multiple rows. Instead `return $Array` after the loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [getters and setters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) for accessing a value from a class. This has the added benefit that its easier to add new functionality inside the class and still get the same thing back from the getter.

```
class Classname
{
    private $myArray = array();

    public function getMyArray()
    {
        return $this->myarray();
    }

    public function Functionname()
    {
        $sql = 'mysql query';
        $result = mysql_query($sql);    

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
           $this->myArray[] = $row;
        }

        return $this;

    }
}
```

Later you can call

```
$myClass = new Classname();   

if( in_array('foo', $myClass->Functionname()->getMyArray() ))
{
    echo 'BAR!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a public property

class Classname{
    public $array;

```
public function Functionname(){
$sql = 'mysql query';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$sgArray[] = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$this->array[] = $row;
}
return $this->array;
```

Comment: there's error: adding should be `$this->array[]` not `$this->array` 'cause it overrides the array each time on each loop

Comment: yeah true wrote it quick, but if you look at his code it returns in the loop so it only returns one record as well heh.

Answer (score 0):

since `functionname` is public, just make it (or a similar method) return the data you want...

```
class Classname{
    public function GetResultSet(){
        $sql = 'mysql query';
        return mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
    }
}
```

then outside the class...

```
$ResultSet = $Classname->GetResultSet();

while($row = $ResultSet){
   return $Array[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for your class and call the function.

```
Classname $obj;
$Array = $obj->functionname();
```

And do not return inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassName {
    public function FunctionName() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ...";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $sgArray = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $sgArray[] = $row;
        }

        return $sgArray;
    }
}

$obj = new ClassName();
$var = "some value ";
$arr = $obj->FunctionName();

if (in_array($var, $arr)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

EDIT: This assumes `$sgArray` is merely a temporary value, and not part of the class.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to create an instance variable:

$obj = new Classname();
//$obj is now your instance variable

//now get the method from other class using the instance variable you created:
$array = $obj->Functionname();

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!